# linq query not working for database "ş", "ţ" characters

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

The searchString comes from user input, a textbox.
When I input something like "iasi" or "iaşi" it should return the results if the value is "Iaşi" in the database, but it's not returning anything.
Note that it's working for database characters like "ă", "â". 
Database and columns have "Latin1_General_CI_AI" Collation, column type is nvarchar.
The HTML Meta Content-Type tag is "text/html; charset=UTF-8".

View:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <p>
                @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </p>
        }
```

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {
        var db = new dbEntities();
        var query = from i in db.Table1
                           select i;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            query = query.Where(s => s.Column1.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.Column2.Contains(searchString));

        return View(query);
    }
```

Comment: For debug purposes, call query.ToList and view the contents. This way you see what strings are in  query and you can compare them to your searchString

Answer (score 0):

Just ruling out the obvious... is there any possibility this could be because your two search strings begin with a letter "`i`" whereas your database content string begins with a letter "`l`"?

Comment: In my example the search strings begin with "i" (lowercase) and database content string begins "I" uppercase, that works and that is not the problem. The problem is searching for strings with "ş", "ţ" etc, doesn't return any result!